# how to define libjnisolfs.so in Android.mk (manifest file)

Tags: android

I am using Android 4.2 in Windows 7.

Added NDK Builder, but i need to define libjnisolfs.so in Android.mk. I want to know is this a static or shared library and how to add it in manifest.

I my project folder say (MyApp), I have added this file in 
`jni/libjnisolfs.so`

and also in 
`libs/armeabi/libjnisolfs.so`

Comment: no need to add .so files path in manifest files and all.. it will get automatic reference .. you need to do .. System.loadlibrary(sofilename)

Answer (score 0):

If you already build your library and won't want to change it in future you can remove jni folder from MyApp project root. In java code add loading of library:

```
static
{
    System.loadLibrary("jnisolfs");
}
```

and declare native method, for examle:

```
public native String getMyData();
```